# How to convert android Map V1 to Map V2 for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, location

I have the android application which uses Android Map V1. Now I want to update the application with some special features but when i Try to update the application the map v1 is deprecated

I want to convert my application from MAP V1 to V2 please any one help me in this

Note: I am using overlay in V1 but the V2 is not supporting that

```
public class AlertsMapActivity extends MapActivity {
private static final int DIALOG_CONFIRM_REMOVE = 0;
private static final int DIALOG_CONFIRM_SAVE = 1;
private static final double ZOOM_PADDING_FACTOR = 1.2;

public class PopupViewHolder {
    public Button buttonDelete,
            buttonCreate,
            buttonSave;
    public EditText editTitle,
            editSnippet;
}

private Geocoder geocoder;
private LocationManager locMan;
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private MenuInflater menuInflater;

private MapView mapView;
private View popupView;
private Button buttonClear;

private MapController controller;

private MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;
private AlertsOverlay alertsOverlay;
private SearchOverlay searchOverlay;
private RadiusOverlay radiusOverlay;

private ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    G.density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    // Create popup
    popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_popup, null);

    Button popupCreate, popupDelete, popupSave;
    popupCreate = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_create);
    popupCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GeoPoint point = (GeoPoint) mapView.getTag(R.id.tag_geopoint);
            PopupViewHolder popupVH = (PopupViewHolder) popupView.getTag();
            String title = popupVH.editTitle.getText().toString(), snippet = popupVH.editSnippet.getText().toString();
            Alert alert = new Alert(point, title, snippet, radiusOverlay.getRadius(), C.DEFAULT_EXPIRATION);

            // Add to db
            long id = dbHelper.addAlert(alert);
            // TODO select vibrate/alert tone
            // TODO allow user to set expiration
            // TODO scheduling
            // TODO styling for edittexts in popup
            // TODO styling for listalertsactivity

            if (id >= 0) {
                // Register proximity alert with locman
                double lat = point.getLatitudeE6() / 1e6, lon = point.getLongitudeE6() / 1e6;
                locMan.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radiusOverlay.getRadius(), C.DEFAULT_EXPIRATION, Utils.createAlertPI(getApplicationContext(), id));
                alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();
                searchOverlay.clear();

                mapView.postInvalidate();
                mapView.removeView(popupView);
                radiusOverlay.clearUI();

                Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.alert_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.error_saving_alert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    popupDelete = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    popupDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRM_REMOVE);
        }
    });
    popupSave = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    popupSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRM_SAVE);
        }
    });

    PopupViewHolder popupVH = new PopupViewHolder();
    popupVH.buttonCreate = popupCreate;
    popupVH.buttonDelete = popupDelete;
    popupVH.buttonSave = popupSave;
    popupVH.editTitle = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    popupVH.editSnippet = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.text_snippet);
    popupView.setTag(popupVH);

    // Create mapview
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alerts_map);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    // Configure mapview
    controller = mapView.getController();
    controller.setZoom(C.DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Show last known location if available
    Location loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (loc != null) controller.setCenter(location2GeoPoint(loc));

    // Overlays
    List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    Drawable alertMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_alert);
    alertsOverlay = new AlertsOverlay(dbHelper, popupView, alertMarker);

    myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();

    Drawable searchMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_search);
    searchOverlay = new SearchOverlay(popupView, searchMarker);

    List<IItemOverlay> itemOverlays = new ArrayList<IItemOverlay>();
    itemOverlays.add(alertsOverlay);
    itemOverlays.add(searchOverlay);
    Drawable radiusMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radius_handle);
    radiusOverlay = new RadiusOverlay(this, itemOverlays, radiusMarker);

    overlays.add(radiusOverlay);
    overlays.add(searchOverlay);
    overlays.add(alertsOverlay);
    overlays.add(myLocOverlay);

    //Clear button
    buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            radiusOverlay.clearUI();
            mapView.removeView(popupView);
            searchOverlay.clear();
            mapView.postInvalidate();
            alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(newIntent.getAction())) {
        String query = newIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }

}

private void doSearch(final String query) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, getString(R.string.searching));
    searchOverlay.clear();

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
        private List<Address> results = null;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                results = geocoder.getFromLocationName(params[0], 5, C.SG_BOUND_SOUTH, C.SG_BOUND_WEST, C.SG_BOUND_NORTH, C.SG_BOUND_EAST);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                for (Address result : results)
                    searchOverlay.addItem(new SearchResult(result));

                // Zoom/pan map to fit all results
                zoomToFit(searchOverlay);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            if (!success) Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.no_results_returned, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Hide spinner
            if (pd != null) pd.cancel();

            SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(AlertsMapActivity.this, RecentSearchProvider.AUTHORITY, RecentSearchProvider.MODE);
            suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, results.size() + " result" + ((results.size() == 1) ? "" : "s"));
        }

    }.execute(query);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();
    myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLocOverlay.disableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    dbHelper.close();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_clear:
        List<Alert> alerts = dbHelper.getAlerts();
        for (Alert alert : alerts)
            locMan.removeProximityAlert(Utils.createAlertPI(getApplicationContext(), alert.getId()));

        dbHelper.clearData();
        alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();
        mapView.postInvalidate();
        mapView.removeView(popupView);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_test:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WakeUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_list_alerts:
        intent = new Intent(this, ListAlertsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_clear_search:
        searchOverlay.clear();
        mapView.postInvalidate();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_search:
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_zoom_alerts:
        if (alertsOverlay.size() > 0) zoomToFit(alertsOverlay);
        else Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_alerts_to_show, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_options:
        intent = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_CONFIRM_REMOVE:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_remove).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Alert alertItem = (Alert) mapView.getTag(R.id.tag_item);

                locMan.removeProximityAlert(Utils.createAlertPI(getApplicationContext(), alertItem.getId()));
                int numRemoved = dbHelper.removeAlert(alertItem.getId());
                if (numRemoved > 0) {
                    alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();

                    mapView.postInvalidate();
                    mapView.removeView(popupView);
                    radiusOverlay.clearUI();

                    Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.alert_removed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.error_removing_alert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        return builder.show();
    case DIALOG_CONFIRM_SAVE:
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_save).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                PopupViewHolder popupVH = (PopupViewHolder) popupView.getTag();
                String title = popupVH.editTitle.getText().toString(), snippet = popupVH.editSnippet.getText().toString();
                Alert alertItem = (Alert) mapView.getTag(R.id.tag_item);
                Alert newAlert = new Alert(alertItem.getPoint(), title, snippet, radiusOverlay.getRadius(), C.DEFAULT_EXPIRATION);
                newAlert.setId(alertItem.getId());

                int numUpdated = dbHelper.updateAlert(newAlert);
                if (numUpdated > 0) {
                    alertsOverlay.itemsUpdated();

                    mapView.postInvalidate();
                    mapView.removeView(popupView);
                    radiusOverlay.clearUI();

                    Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.changes_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AlertsMapActivity.this, R.string.error_saving_changes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        return builder.show();

    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id, args);
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

private <T extends IItemOverlay> void zoomToFit(T overlay) {
    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    List<? extends OverlayItem> items = overlay.getItems();
    for (OverlayItem item : items) {
        GeoPoint p = item.getPoint();

        int lat = p.getLatitudeE6();
        int lon = p.getLongitudeE6();

        maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
        minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
        maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
        minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);
    }

    controller.zoomToSpan((int)(ZOOM_PADDING_FACTOR*overlay.getLatSpanE6()), (int)(ZOOM_PADDING_FACTOR*overlay.getLonSpanE6()));
    controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2));
}

/**
 * Converts a Location to a GeoPoint
 * 
 * @param loc
 *            The Location to convert.
 * @return A GeoPoint representation of the Location.
 */
private GeoPoint location2GeoPoint(Location loc) {
    return new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1e6), (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1e6));
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your code ? Have you checked Google map V2 guide? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: Added the code for your reference

Comment: The overlay is removed from the google map v2. so have to achieve your functionality using the other google map v2 features like ploygon,polyline.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

[Google maps V2 Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) and [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278325/java-lang-nullpointerexception-googlemaps-v2/20278406#20278406)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from v1 works in v2, you need to completely start over to convert it from v1.

you should take a look at the documentation on how to use Google Maps v2

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/