# error inflating class fragment ~ set content view

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an api. All steps are done. This map was working. I don't remember why I remove google play service library and load again. subsequently this error occured.

manifest.xml;

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value= my api key />
```

google_map.xml;

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Log cat;

```
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.example.cryptodlp/com.example.cryptodlp.GoogleMapFragment}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.example.cryptodlp.GoogleMapFragment.onCreate(GoogleMapFragment.java:35)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    ... 11 more
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-09 11:43:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(28745):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Check your xml file line num 6.

Comment: it shows the fragment part

Comment: Try to clean both projects (google play services lib and your project). Bi the way, add this in your manifest:     <meta-data 
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your xml :

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in your manifest file add this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this link and follow the steps that i have mentioned in that answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278325/java-lang-nullpointerexception-googlemaps-v2/20278406#20278406

Comment: thanks.. I used wrongly this meta-data before.. now it worked :)